# How to group an array of ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array:

```
<% @widgets.each do |w| %>
...
<% end %>
```

How can I display them in groups? Let's say by 4:

```
<div>1, 2, 3, 4</div>
<div>5, 6, 7, 8</div>
etc.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. You both replied 3min ago. I don't know which answer to mark as valid :( I will wait and see who was first.

Comment: All things being equal, I always give it to the person with less reputation :) (Also, his first answer beat mine by 52 seconds; hover the "xx mins ago" to see the actual time as a tooltip.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `each_slice(n)`:

```
require 'erb'

@widgets = (1..8).to_a

template = <<EOF
<% @widgets.each_slice(4) do |w| %>
  <div><%= w.join(', ') %></div>
<% end %>
EOF

puts ERB.new(template).result(binding)
# =>
  <div>1, 2, 3, 4</div>
  <div>5, 6, 7, 8</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the specific example you gave, you want [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
<% @widgets.each_slice(4) do |ws| %>
  <div><%= ws.join(', ') %></div>
<% end %>
```

You might also be interested in [`each_cons`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) (each consecutive, e.g. "1,2,3", "2,3,4", "3,4,5", etc.) or [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for arbitrary groupings.

```
Person = Struct.new(:name,:age,:male) do
  def inspect
    "<#{'fe' unless male}male '#{name}' #{age}>"
  end
end

all = [
  Person.new("Diane",  12, false),
  Person.new("Harold", 28, true),
  Person.new("Gavin",  38, true),
  Person.new("Judy",   55, false),
  Person.new("Dirk",   59, true)
]

p all.group_by(&:male)
#=> {
#=>   false=>[ <female 'Diane' 12>, <female 'Judy' 55> ],
#=>   true =>[ <male 'Gavin' 38>, <male 'Harold' 28>,  <male 'Dirk' 59> ]
#=> }

p all.group_by{ |person| (person.age / 10) * 10 }
#=> {10=>[<female 'Diane' 12>],
#=>  20=>[<male 'Harold' 28>],
#=>  30=>[<male 'Gavin' 38>],
#=>  50=>[<female 'Judy' 55>, <male 'Dirk' 59>]}
```